# Is there a way to have a dynamic type slice in Go?

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have a standard response built in PHP for microservices that I want to replicate in Go.
In particular, the "data" element of the response array can have anything.

Example

```
$response['data'] = [];
$response['data']['entities'] = [ objects that implements toArray() ]
$response['data']['quantity'] = 1
```

Problem is that Data differs per endpoint.

So one option I was thinking is in each endpoint (controller, action, etc) declare a Data struct that I would use in the `StandardResponse.Data` struct.

But how can I achieve that? Using interfaces?

Sorry I am new to Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `interface{}` is one way to do it. Something like:

```
type StandardResponse struct {
   Error    bool
   ErrorMsg string
   Data     interface{}
}
```

Marshaling this to JSON will work assuming the underlying type of `interface{}` supports it.

Comment: Could you please provide an implementation example mixing types? I cannot see how it works... because well... I am newbie in go